# The logical order of execution plan of the SQL query with more than one join

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016, query

I know the logical order of execution of the SQL query which is:

```
FROM
ON
JOIN
WHERE
GROUP BY
WITH CUBE or WITH ROLLUP
HAVING
SELECT
DISTINCT
ORDER BY
TOP
```

What will happen if there are more than one join in the query for instance if we have a query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM user_branch T1
INNER JOIN dimcustomer2 T2
   ON T1.BRANCH_CODE = T2.BRANCH_CODE
INNER JOIN customer_guarantee T3
   ON T3.CUSTOMER_NUM = T2.CUSTOMER_NUM
```

some example data:

```
customer_guarantee:    CUSTOMER_NUM      BRANCH_CODE
                      -------------------------------
                           A                X
                           B                X
                           C                Y
                           D                Z



 user_branch:           USER_ID          BRANCH_CODE    
                      --------------------------------
                           U1               Y



 dimcustomer2:         CUSTOMER_NUM      BRANCH_CODE      
                      --------------------------------
                           A                Y
                           B                Y
                           C                Y
                           D                Z
```

How will this execute? Which join will be executed first? And what if there are
different kind of joins in the query? What would be the order of executing joins in that case? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ exactly the logical order . I've changed my question. thanks

Comment: The docs say you can specify `OPTION (FORCE ORDER)`. [G. Force the join order to match the order in the query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/option-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @Luuk use the `FORCE`...

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: The question was "How will this execute?" Not "in which logical order will this execute?".   The option I gave is there to "to force the query plan to use the join order specified by the query", in other words if specified than the order in which the joins are executed is (or should be?) known.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ my question is exactly "in which logical order will this execute"

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ  I provide you guys with example data.

Comment: @Pantea I assume this order is valid for standard SQL. I was wondering if mySQL works in the same order too? If yes why does mySQL allow to use alias (made in select) in groupby?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way to determine the logical order of joins is to replace the first inner join in your example with a left outer join:

```
SELECT *
FROM user_branch T1
LEFT  JOIN dimcustomer2 T2
   ON T1.BRANCH_CODE = T2.BRANCH_CODE
INNER JOIN customer_guarantee T3
   ON T3.CUSTOMER_NUM = T2.CUSTOMER_NUM
```

Let us assume that some rows in `T1` have no matches in `T2`. More specifically, let us assume these are the three tables:

```
    T1                         T2                           T3
                                                   
BRANCH_CODE          BRANCH_CODE  CUSTOMER_NUM          CUSTOMER_NUM
-----------          -----------  ------------          ------------
11                   11           230                   120
12                   12           235                   170
13                   15           260                   230
14                                                      235
15                                                      245
                                                        250
                                                        260
                                                        270
```

There are two joins here and two possibilities in which order they are executed.

#### 1. LEFT JOIN, then INNER JOIN

If the left join evaluates first, then its result will have nulls in the `T2` columns where `T1` rows had no match:

```
T1.BRANCH_CODE  T2.BARNCH_CODE  T2.CUSTOMER_NUM
--------------  --------------  ---------------
11              11              230
12              12              235
13              (null)          (null)
14              (null)          (null)
15              15              260
```

Joining that result further with `T3` using an inner join on a condition that uses a `T2` column will eliminate the non-matches – and, therefore, corresponding `T1` rows, – because a null cannot satisfy the join's equals condition:

```
T1.BRANCH_CODE  T2.BARNCH_CODE  T2.CUSTOMER_NUM  T3.CUSTOMER_NUM
--------------  --------------  ---------------  ---------------
11              11              230              230
12              12              235              235
15              15              260              260
```

This way some of `T1` rows will be excluded from the final result set.

#### 2. INNER JOIN, then LEFT JOIN

Now if the inner join is executed first, then it will produce a result set containing the rows from `T2` and `T3` that match the inner join's condition:

```
T2.BARNCH_CODE  T2.CUSTOMER_NUM  T3.CUSTOMER_NUM
--------------  ---------------  ---------------
11              230              230
12              235              235
15              260              260
```

When this result set is then outer-joined to `T1`, `T1` being on the outer side, you will get a final result containing all the rows from `T1` and those from the `T2`-`T3` inner join that match the outer join condition:

```
T1.BRANCH_CODE  T2.BARNCH_CODE  T2.CUSTOMER_NUM  T3.CUSTOMER_NUM
--------------  --------------  ---------------  ---------------
11              11              230              230
12              12              235              235
13              (null)          (null)           (null)
14              (null)          (null)           (null)
15              15              260              260
```

Therefore, this second interpretation would mean that all `T1` rows should be present in the result.

---

Since these two interpretations give such different results, it is clear that only one can be true. Executing the query, you will see that actually it is the first one. That means that **logically, the joins are executed in the order they are specified in the `FROM` clause**.

### Syntax variations

Note that the conclusion above applies to the most conventional join syntax, namely this:

```
FROM
  T1
  ... JOIN T2 ON ...
  ... JOIN T3 ON ...
  ...
```

Your example matches that pattern, so the conclusion applies to it as well. However, there are variations worth mentioning where our conclusion does not apply, or at least not as straightforwardly.

#### 1. Nested JOIN syntax

Syntactically, a join may be specified inside another join, like this:

```
FROM
  T1
  JOIN
    T2
    JOIN T3 ON ..
  ON ...
```

In the above case, `JOIN T2` is encountered before `JOIN T3`. However the former join's declaration is not complete at that point: its `ON` subclause is the one at the end and is logically evaluated only after the `JOIN T3 ON ...` part. So in this case, `T2` is joined to `T3` first, then the result of the join is joined to `T1`.

You *could* still argue that our conclusion stands here, although it is not as clear-cut in this situation. We concluded that the joins are evaluated in the order they are *specified* in the `FROM` clause. In this example, the first join we encounter as we parse the `FROM` clause, is not yet completely specified by the time the second one is.

#### 2. Mixing comma joins and conventional joins

Prior to introduction of the explicit `JOIN` syntax, joins were specified like this:

```
FROM
  T1,
  T2,
  T3
WHERE
  <joining conditions, filter conditions>
```

This type of join, sometimes referred to as comma join, is still supported by most, if not all, platforms, including SQL Server.

Without a joining condition, a comma join is essentially a cross join. A joining condition makes it an inner join. You can see, though, that the joining condition in this case comes in an entirely different clause, the `WHERE` clause.

Now, SQL Server allows you to mix comma joins and conventional joins in the same `FROM` clause. When you have a mix of joins like this:

```
FROM
  T1,
  T2
  JOIN T3 ON ... ,
  T4 ...
```

SQL Server will evaluate each individual comma-separated item independently of the others before cross-joining them all together. So in the above case, the `T2 JOIN T3 ON ...` join will be evaluated before its result is cross-joined to `T1` (to be further filtered down by any joining condition that might be found the `WHERE` clause). Our conclusion does not apply at all here. However, you can see that a very different syntax comes into play in this case.

I am discussing the mixed syntax in slightly more detail in my answer on Stack Overflow: [The multi-part identifier could not be bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314134/the-multi-part-identifier-could-not-be-bound/7314936#7314936).

Comment: The second join cannot possibly be parsed before the first because it references a column that's coming from the first join. I find the whole notion of _logically executing_ improper, because query execution belongs to the _physical_ domain.

Comment: My guess is the OP may be viewing it somewhat differently. And I think it's indeed conceivable, even though incorrect, to imagine that the second join is between T2 and T3 rather than between the result of T1-T2 join and the T3 table. In fact, I think that's why the question has been asked in the first place.

Answer (score 9):

I'm afraid the phrase "logical execution" does not make much sense; query execution by definition is physical materialization of a result set. I think what you mean by "logical execution" is the query compilation, the phase where the query syntax and semantic meaning is analyzed and the query plan is prepared to implement said semantic meaning.

Joined tables<sup>1</sup> in a query are always evaluated left to right (or top to bottom):

```
select ... from t_a                   -- evaluated first
           join t_b                   -- evaluated second
             on t_a.c1 = t_b.c3
           join t_x                   -- evaluated third
             on t_b.c4 = t_x.c5
           ...
```

You can verify this yourself if you try to reference in the `ON` clause a column that belongs to a table included later in the evaluation sequence. This will fail to compile:

```
select ... from t_a
           join t_b
             on t_a.c1 = t_c.c8       -- t_c is not known yet
           join t_c                   
           ...
```

After the query is parsed, the execution plan can perform joins in *any* order that maintains the query semantics. As the [manual says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15),

> The order of table sources after the `FROM` keyword does not affect the result set that is returned.

[This Q&A](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/125422/what-does-the-position-of-the-on-clause-actually-mean) is somewhat related.

---

1 - A `joined_table` clause consists of two `table_source`s and their corresponding `ON` clause.

Comment: The language definition tells you what the result/output/value is given the input. This is done by giving the result/output/value for subexpressions in terms of their constituent inputs. This specification of the result is termed "logical evaluation/execution" & the expression tree traversal order involved is termed "logical evaluation/execution order". Although if the question is posed using that term it would help if it defined it for those who don't know it. It has nothing to do with "physical" "execution" except that that must return the specified result.

Answer (score 2):

All the JOINs actually belong to the FROM clause. Semantically, it does not make a difference in which order the JOINs are written, as long as you maintain the ON clauses and don't use LEFT/RIGHT OUTER JOIN clauses. Said differently, the output of the FROM and the JOIN clauses is a single large relation where it clearly does not really matter in which order the columns are. This is very important because this is an important optimization opportunity for the database optimizer: it makes sense to execute the JOINs among the smaller relations first if the WHERE conditions might prune it. This way it might be more feasible for the database to cache those columns while working on the rest of the result set.